# Limited access permission cant see parent folder in library in SharePoint 2013/2016

Tags: document-library

If you have folder structure in Document library like

Folder1-->
      Folder2-->
           Folder3-->
               File

and a user has permission to only file inside Folder3. User will automatically get Limited access to whole Library .

The problem for the user is, when he clicks on Document library, he cant see anything. he has to exclusively navigate to Folder3 url to see the file.This happens in Sharepoint 2013 and 2016.

In 2010 its working fine.

Tree View is one of the workaround, but it shows whole structure which we dont want.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to see all the folders if i have permission to File within Folder.means i should see top level(parent) folders of the file. otherwise i have to go to the file using URL only!